# JCE editor adding extra &nbsp; inside empty div in Joomla 2.5

Tags: editor, joomla2.5

In the JCE editor while creating the content at the editor window at source mode if I give

```
<div class="text"></div>
```

toggle to design and then again toggle back to source its adding `&nbsp;` inbetween the `div` as

```
<div class="text">&nbsp;</div>.
```

How to fix this issue. Please help on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this, but this could be done by,

Components --> JCE Editor --> Global Configuration --> Under 'cleanup and output', change 'keep non-breaking spaces' to 'no'. Save it and try now.

Comment: I have used older version JCE once upgrade to new version i got that option. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

In a newer version of JCE there is now also an option to 'Pad Empty tags'. If you set this to 'no' it will refrain from adding

Components --> JCE Editor --> Global Configuration --> Pad Empty Tags